# copy data to table but keep the filter active

Tags: excel, vba, filter

My code copies table data to an array and then this array is copied to the main file to a table.

Is there any way for the filter to be active when the data is copied to it.
Now when I copy the data I have to reapply the filter each time.

(filter is not set to a specific value and can change) I guess my question is, is there any way to refresh the filter?

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub readingarray()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim arr
Dim Itm
Dim rng As Range
Dim stringarray As Variant
Dim rowcount As Long, columncount As Long
'array of work files
stringarray = Array("test.xlsm", "test 2.xlsm", "test 3.xlsm", "test 4.xlsm", "test 5.xlsm", _
                    "test 6.xlsm", "test 7.xlsm", "test 8.xlsm", "test 9.xlsm", "test 10.xlsm", _
                    "test 11.xlsm", "test 12.xlsm")

     On Error Resume Next
     
    
      'copy shibuzim table from work files to main files including only filtered celled
        For Each Itm In stringarray
           arr = GetArrayFromFilteredRange(Workbooks(Itm).Worksheets("shibuz").ListObjects("LeaveTracker").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
             Set table_list_object = Workbooks("shibuzim 2 updated.xlsm").Worksheets("shibuz").ListObjects("LeaveTracker")
             Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
    
        
             rowcount = UBound(arr, 1)
             columncount = UBound(arr, 2)
             table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Resize(rowcount - 1, columncount - 1).Value = arr
        Next Itm
        
      On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub
    'function to filter only filtered cells
    Function GetArrayFromFilteredRange(rng As Range) As Variant
        Dim arr As Variant
       'copy to help sheet
       helper.Cells.Clear
       
        rng.Copy helper.Range("A1")
        arr = helper.UsedRange.Value
        
        GetArrayFromFilteredRange = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Sheets("shibuz").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be sure to include an explanation, not just code. Thank you.